# Non-numeric argument to binary operator in R: Survival Analysis

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I'm not sure why I get this error. I get the graph after, sure, but I don't know what is causing the error.

```
plot(survfit(Surv(time,DEATH_EVENT) ~ hypertension, data=HF), main = "Hypertension Survival Distributions", xlab = "Length of Survival",ylab="Probability of Survival",col=c("blue","red")) +
  legend("topright", legend=c("Absent", "Present"),fill=c("blue","red"),bty="n")
```

```
Error in plot(survfit(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ hypertension, data = HF),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

*This*, however, works wonders:

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(time,DEATH_EVENT) ~ hypertension, data=HF),
           data = HF, 
           censor.shape="|",  
           conf.int = FALSE, 
           ggtheme = theme_bw())
```

Comment: Do you want `qplot` from ggplot instead of `plot`?

Comment: Sorry, i mean to say `autoplot`

Answer (score 1):

If you alter some of your parameters, it should work as expected:

```r
plot(survfit(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ hypertension, data = HF), main = "Hypertension Survival Distributions", xlab = "Length of Survival", ylab = "Probability of Survival", col = c("blue","red"))
legend(x = 1, y = 1, legend = c("Absent", "Present"), col = c("blue","red"), lty = 1)
```

NB. change `legend(x = 1` to "whatever the max x axis value is", e.g. `legend(x = 1000` to place the legend in the top right.